# Light-emitting diode luminous intensity at sub-mA currents

Tags: led

I am trying to find a graph or table that relates the light intensity (either relative, absolute, or total luminous flux) of a light-emitting diode at the low range of drive currents - below 1 mA and ideally down to nA and pA levels.

Most, if not all, datasheets from manufacturers tend to specify output brightness down to 1 mA, but not lower (as usually, it is not application-relevant). I've made an honest effort to parse the literature available to me, but have failed to find a reference for light output over a broader range of currents.

Alternatively, I'm also looking for some first-pass approximation for the relationship of current and light output. At higher currents, the common assumption is a linear dependency. I doubt linearity is maintained at much lower currents, but I am interested in what the curve would be and if it is monotonic and how it can be expressed mathematically.

(N.B. I hesitate whether to ask this at physics.stackexchange.com or here. Hopefully someone with overlapping expertise can chime in!)

Comment: My experience is that luminous flux at these low levels varies wildly between LEDs and even LEDs of the same batch. Because of this, nobody bothers to produce specs this low. Best bet may be to get a few of different batches and run your own analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not many manufactures will specify the luminous intensity at low levels because many LEDs have a minimum required current. I have tested some high power 3W LEDs at low currents and the LEDs begin to flicker and turn off at about 10 mA.

There are some LEDs with high luminous intensity and low maximum current (e.g. 20-50 mA) that will emit a measurable intensity at very low currents. One such LED is the high efficacy OSRAM [LA E63F](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-4111674/LA%20E63F.pdf) which targets the automotive industry.  This amber LED has a luminous flux (Q<sub>V</sub>) of 12.7 candela where I<sub>V</sub>:30°.

At very low current the illuminance (E<sub>V</sub>), measured in lux (lumens/m²), is 1% of the illuminance at 50 mA.

[image]

> 8) In the range where the line of the graph is broken, you must expect
>   higher differences between single LEDs within one packing unit.
>
> 7) Due to the special conditions of the  manufacturing processes of LED,
>   the typical data or calculated correlations of technical parameters
>   can only reflect statistical figures. These do not necessarily
>   correspond to the actual parameters of each single product, which
>   could differ from the typical data and calculated correlations or the
>   typical  characteristic line. If requested, e.g. because of technical
>   improvements, these typ. data will be changed without any further
>   notice.

---

> At higher currents, the common assumption is a linear dependency. I
>   doubt linearity is maintained at much lower currents,

It's actually the opposite. The current vs. Q<sub>V</sub> is linear at low currents and drops off as the current rises.

[image]

As you can see the Cree XP3G has a test current of 350 mA at 100% of rated luminous flux (Q<sub>V</sub>). At 700 mA (2X) the Q<sub>V</sub> is less than 200%.  Whereas at 50% test current (175 mA) the Q<sub>V</sub> is 50%.

You can assume the luminous flux will drop at a linear rate as current decreases from the published test current within the operating range of values.

[image]

Comment: A delayed thank you for the information! Since I'm working on an application that will be able to accurately measure light intensities, I intend to characterize some LEDs at low currents, and I will follow up with the results.